# Images not filling the whole width on mobile

Tags: css, image, mobile, blogger

I'm trying to make my photos fill the whole width of the screen when on mobile. I've tried most of the stuff advised here for such problems, but I can't seem to achieve it.

This is the code. I've tried changing the width to 100%, or even min-width: 100%, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
.post-image img {
    width:360px;
    height:auto;
}
```

My website:
https://www.lakadpilipinas.com/

Help please.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 100vw to size the image on 100% of the vendor width.

```
.post-image img {
width:100vw;
height:auto;
}
```

The 100% aren't 100% of the screen width, but of the width of the image or of the .post-image element.

To prevent the image from taking up all the space of a laptop or tablet screen, you can also add `max-width: 8cm;` for example.

```
.post-image img {
width:100vw;
height:auto;
max-width: 8cm;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work too.